# Migration Spring v2 to Spring v4 for org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation

Tags: java, spring, java-17, spring-4, spring2.x

### Introduction

I'm currently using `EnableBinding` , `StreamListener` from Spring v2: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/2.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/stream/annotation/package-summary.html

#### The code of my project that uses these annotations:

```java
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.enterprise.production.model.exceptions.ProductionStoreException;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyProductionMessage;
import com.enterprise.production.stream.service.ProductionStoreService;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ProductionMessageConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private ProductionStoreService productionService;
    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;

    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void handleEnergyProductionMessage(@Payload EnergyProductionMessage energyProductionMessage) throws ProductionStoreException {
        Instant start = clock.instant();

        log.debug("Processing energy productions message with original interval: {}|{}|{}", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(), energyProductionMessage.getUsername(),
                    energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId());
        log.info("Processing {} energy productions ", energyProductionMessage.getSolarEnergies().size());

        productionService.saveProductions(energyProductionMessage);
        log.debug("Ending energy productions message with original interval: {}|{}|{}: ended in {}ms", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getUsername(), energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId(), Duration
                         .between(start, clock.instant()).toMillis());
        Instant startNormalization = clock.instant();
        log.debug("Processing energy productions message with normalization 30m: {}|{}|{}", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(), energyProductionMessage.getUsername(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId());
        productionService.saveProductions30m(energyProductionMessage);
        log.debug("Ending energy productions message with normalization 30m: {}|{}|{}: ended in {}ms", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getUsername(), energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId(), Duration
                         .between(startNormalization, clock.instant()).toMillis());
    }

    @StreamListener("errorChannel")
    public void error(Message<?> message) {
        log.error("Fail to read message with error '{}'", message.getPayload());
    }

}
```

### Problem

I need to migrate to Spring v4 but these annotations are not available in Spring v4: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/4.0.0/org/springframework/cloud/stream/annotation/package-summary.html

### Question

Someone does know how to migrate these annotation Spring v2 to Spring v4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation you are using are deprecated and mentionned in the appropriate section of 3.2.x of Spring Cloud Stream [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.9/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-preface-notable-deprecations)

> Annotation-based programming model. Basically the @EnableBInding, @StreamListener and all related annotations are now deprecated in favor of the functional programming model. See [Spring Cloud Function support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.9/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function) for more details.

When following the link above, you'll see that

> Since Spring Cloud Stream v2.1, another alternative for defining stream handlers and sources is to use build-in support for Spring Cloud Function where they can be expressed as beans of type `java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer]`.

In order to move to v4, you need to declare your actual configuration of `@StreamListener` to actual Spring beans defined in a specific class with `@org.springframework.context.annotationConfiguration` annotation

```java
@Configuration
public class ProductionMessageConsumerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ProductionStoreService productionService;
    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<EnergyProductionMessage> consumeEnergyProductionMessage() {
        return energyProductionMessage -> {
            Instant start = clock.instant();

            log.debug("Processing energy productions message with original interval: {}|{}|{}", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(), energyProductionMessage.getUsername(),
                    energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId());
            log.info("Processing {} energy productions ", energyProductionMessage.getSolarEnergies().size());

            productionService.saveProductions(energyProductionMessage);
            log.debug("Ending energy productions message with original interval: {}|{}|{}: ended in {}ms", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getUsername(), energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId(), Duration
                         .between(start, clock.instant()).toMillis());
            Instant startNormalization = clock.instant();
            log.debug("Processing energy productions message with normalization 30m: {}|{}|{}", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(), energyProductionMessage.getUsername(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId());
            productionService.saveProductions30m(energyProductionMessage);
            log.debug("Ending energy productions message with normalization 30m: {}|{}|{}: ended in {}ms", energyProductionMessage.getTenantId(),
                 energyProductionMessage.getUsername(), energyProductionMessage.getDeviceId(), Duration
                         .between(startNormalization, clock.instant()).toMillis());
        }
    }

}
```

For the error handling part, by defaut it creates a log with the message payload but you can follow this [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.9/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#polled-errors) on how to handle it manually

Answer (score 1):

These annotation are depreciated. You can uses Consumer to defined it

```
@Service
public class ProductionMessageConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private ProductionStoreService productionService;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<EnergyProductionMessage> handleEnergyProductionMessage() {
        retrun energyProductionMessage -> {
            ...
            productionService.saveProductions(energyProductionMessage);
            ....
        }
    }

}
```

Please also check this answer
[@EnableBinding @deprecated as of 3.1 in favor of functional programming model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576021)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the `Consumer`class is from this library `java.util.function.Consumer` or another  ?

Comment: When I use your code example I have this warning `'@Configuration' is missing on a class defining Spring Beans`do you know how to solve it ?